# When bottemsheet is expanded how to stop other events in activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

In my android application I have an activity which has recyclerview in it, and also I have floating action button and by clicking on that button bottomsheet will expand. When my bottomsheet is expanded I am showing the dim screen with only few icons which will be there in the bottom of the screen. But, when I tried to scroll on the dim screen(though nothing there on the screen but an empty space) my recyclerview is getting scrolled which is behind the bottomsheet. How can I make recyclerview non scrollable when bottomsheet is expanded.?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dsm="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    dsm:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_for_menu_row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_default_textSize_70px"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/global_default_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/global_default_margin">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row1_item_1"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row1_item_2"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row1_item_3"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row1_item_4"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_for_menu_row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_for_menu_row1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_default_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/global_default_textSize_70px"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/global_default_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/global_default_margin">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row2_item_1"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row2_item_2"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row2_item_3"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_menu_row2_item_4"
            layout="@layout/home_elog_entry_options_view_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_elog_entry_options_close_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_for_menu_row2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/elog_entry_options_view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/global_default_height_200px"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/global_default_height_100px"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home_elog_option_add_button_background"
            android:contentDescription="@string/global_contentDescription" />

        <com.welldoc.platform.android.ui.customcomponents.LatoTextView
            android:id="@+id/elog_entry_option_add_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/elog_entry_options_view"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="&#043;"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/global_default_textSize_80px"
            dsm:textStyle="museosans_bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? if yes, can you please help me. I am also running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add on bottom sheet top layout in xml these lines:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: Hi, I have added my xml code of bottomsheet in my question please see the same and help me.

Comment: also try add this line `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to scroll the `RecyclerView` while the `BottomSheet` is in its `BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED` state with some height set using `setPeekHeight()` or with `BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`, so that your `RecyclerView` and other stuff on the background still can be clicked or scrolled in your case.

The `BottomSheet` is like any widget on the screen doesn't prevent you from manipulating them, because when you touch any widget, you just turn change the focus of the current widget (`BottomSheet` in your case) to another widget (`RecyclerView` in your case).

If you want to change this behavior, then you need to disable the views in the background, while the `BottomSheet` is in a certain state. And there are multiple ways to achieve this.

One of the ways is to add a `View` that covers all other views on the screen (put it following to these views; so that it can be layed on top of them, so that when you touch the screen off the `BottomSheet`, you just can hit this view).

View sample:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

And you need to set this view to be initially `View.GONE`, and whenever you show your `BottomSheet`, set it to `View.VISIBLE` programmatically. For example for certain button is hit, then show the BottomSheet, and the Background view:

```
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED);
            backgroundView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

You can set the background of the View to transparent or semi-transparent so that the RecyclerView and other views on the background still shown.

Then you've to put the logic when this view gets gone again; in my suggested approach you can do something like, when you hit it, then collapse the `BottomSheet` and hide the view:

```
    backgroundView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            background.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Zain I will try this.

Comment: No Zain it didn't work for me though I added view but still I am able to scroll the recyclerview.